ramification index of local fields
Let $L/K$ be a finite extension of local fields with normed discrete valuations $v_k$ and $v_l$. Furthermore, $v_l$ extends $v_k$. The ramification index is $e(L/K):= v_l(\pi_k)$, where $\pi_k$ is a prime element in $\mathcal{O}_K$.
My question: Is $L/K$ unramified?
My idea: Because the valuation $v_k$ is normed, we know for all $x  \in \mathcal{O}_K$, $x$ is a prime element in $\mathcal{O}_K$ if and only if $v_k(x)=1$. Because $v_l$ extends $v_k$, we deduce $v_l$($\pi_k$) = $v_k$($\pi_k$) = $1$, hence $e(L/K) = 1$.

Are you assuming $e(L/K)=1$?

No, but I edited "my idea". I think it should be more clear what I mean now.

This sounds like you are trying to prove that all extensions of local fields are unramified, which is not the case. Take for example $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{p})/\mathbb{Q}_p$ for any prime $p$.

The error in your idea is that the extension of a normalized discrete valuation may not be normalized. So there will be an extension of $v_k$ to $L$, but this will not be the normalized $v_L$ you describe.
As mentioned in the comments, we can look at the extension $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{p})/\mathbb{Q}_p$. We can take the element $p \in \mathbb{Q}_p$ and it is true that $v_{\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{p})}(p) = v_{\mathbb{Q}_p}(p) = 1$, but $v_{\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{p})}(\sqrt{p}) = \frac{1}{2}$ and this is the element that generates the maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{p})$.

I dont see why $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{p})/\mathbb{Q}_p$ is not unramified. Since according to the definition, as far as I see, $e(L/K)$ := $v_l$($\pi_k$), the extension is unramified if $e(L/K)$ = $1$. Which is the case in $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{p})/\mathbb{Q}p$ because
$v{\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{p})}(p)$ = $1$ and $p$ is prime element in $\mathbb{Q}_p$.

@frxrth I still think your confusion is about the normalization of $v_l$. It is true that $e(L/K) = v_l(\pi_k)$ if $v_l$ is normalized. But if you insist that $v_l$ is normalized, it is no longer true that $v_l$ extends $v_k$. So for the normalized valuation, you would have that $v_{\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{p})}(p) = 2$ since $(p) = (\sqrt{p})^2$ and $(\sqrt{p})$ is the maximal ideal of $\mathbb{Q}_p(\sqrt{p})$.

As far as I understand, there are the following two cases: $1$ $vl$ is normalized, then we have $e(L/K)$ = $v_l(\pi_k)$, but it's not sure that $v_l$ extends $v_k$. $2$ $v_l$ is not normalized,but then $e(L/K)$ = $v_l(\pi_k)$ is not neccessarily given, and my idea doesn't work out as your example shows. So my idea would only work if $v_l$ is normalized and $v_l$ extends $v_k$?

@frxrth Yes that's all correct but the point is that $v_l$ can't be both normalized and extending $v_k$ when the extension is ramified.

As you have correctly defined $e(L/K) = v_l(\pi_k)$ when $v_l$ is normalized, what you are assuming is that $v_l$ "lies above" $v_k$ (and not that it extends $v_k$). This means that ${\cal{O}}_L \cap K = {\cal{O}}_K$ and ${\cal{M}}_L \cap {\cal{O}}_K = {\cal{M}}_K$. Therefore, it is certainly possible that $e(L/K)$ may be $> 1$.
